# I need to add row of bunch of input divs using onclick button,, but it gives an error

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my HTML code.
I need to add another row once I click the `<button onclick="Addrow()">Add Employees Row</button>` so I tried using appendchild and insertAdjacentHTML,, but it doesn't work.. Anyone please can help me?

What I am targeting to create is..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKHTd.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Employees Details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/employees.css" />
    <script src="./js/Employees.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="title">Employees Details</div>
        <div class="AddRow">
          <button onclick="Addrow()">Add Employees Row</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contents-grid">
        <div class="contents">
          <div class="Detail-Info-Grid">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Designation" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Prev Company" />
          </div>
          <div class="remove">
            <button>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="submit">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my css code

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
  justify-content: center;

  display: flex;
}

button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
input {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.title {
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateX(65px);
}

.remove {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* vertical-align: center; */
}

.contents {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.contents-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.submit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

My Javascript with error..

```
const ContentsGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("contents-grid");
const Addrow = function () {
  const html = `
  <div class="contents">
          <div class="Detail-Info-Grid">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Designation" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Prev Company" />
          </div>
          <div class="remove">
            <button>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  `;
  ContentsGrid.appendChild(html);
  //   ContentsGrid.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", html);
  //   ContentsGrid.innerHTML += html;
};

// document.getElementById("AddEmployeesRow").addEventListener("click", Addrow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example:

```js
const ContentsGrid = document.querySelector(".contents-grid");
const Addrow = function() {
  const html = `
  <div class="contents">
          <div class="Detail-Info-Grid">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Designation" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Prev Company" />
          </div>
          <div class="remove">
            <button>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  `;
  ContentsGrid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.title {
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateX(65px);
}

.remove {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* vertical-align: center; */
}

.contents {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.contents-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.submit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Employees Details</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="title">Employees Details</div>
      <div class="AddRow">
        <button type="button" onClick="Addrow()">Add Employees Row</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contents-grid" id="contents-grid">
      <div class="contents">
        <div class="Detail-Info-Grid">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Designation" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Prev Company" />
        </div>
        <div class="remove">
          <button>Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It actually works!! Any chance you can give me some hint for how to make 'Remove' button works?

Comment: You need to get the parent node by class and remove it. You can read here how to get closest parent node by class in javascript https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-parent-element-by-class

Answer (score 0):

I am not as familiar with vanila javascript, but I dont see other answers.
Ive never used getElementsByClassName, and I could not get it to work this time.

I am also not sure why you dont just append the input and not re-write your entire html.

if you want to use just append, you would need something like jquery.

if you want to add something simliar to what jquery does with append, that would be  using += and innerHtml.

```js
  const ContentsGrid = document.getElementById("contents-grid");
  const Addrow = function () {
    const html = `
    <div class="contents">
            <div class="Detail-Info-Grid">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Designation" />
              <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" />
              <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
              <input type="text" placeholder="Prev Company" />
              <input type="text" placeholder="Employees" />
            </div>
            <div class="remove">
              <button>Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    `;
    ContentsGrid.innerHTML = html;
    //   ContentsGrid.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", html);
    //   ContentsGrid.innerHTML += html;

  };
  
  // document.getElementById("AddEmployeesRow").addEventListener("click", Addrow);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Employees Details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/employees.css" />
    <script src="./js/Employees.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="title">Employees Details</div>
        <div class="AddRow">
          <button onclick="Addrow()">Add Employees Row</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contents-grid" id="contents-grid">
        <div class="contents">
          <div class="Detail-Info-Grid">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Designation" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Prev Company" />
          </div>
          <div class="remove">
            <button>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="submit">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```